Why are my Aglaonema white joy leaves turning yellow?
I got my plant 1 week ago and all the leaves were white and green I noticed they very quickly started turning yellow with brown spots and drooping.
The instructions with the plant are:
Indirect sunlight
Let the plant most dry out between watering
Mist weekly
I’ve water it once since having it as it felt dry and it’s placed indirectly to the sun.

pictures please
